# Upload image/file using jquery datatables during CRUD operations

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using datatables in Asp.net mvc application and displaying users list in form using [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/). 
I would like to add new record using a popup with image file.
**How can upload image in popup using datatables?**

[image]

**Note**:

- I am using Asp.net MVC 4
- Visual studio 2012
- Datatables
- datatables inline editing and it is working fine in this form

Edit:

```
$(function () {
        $('#ItemsDatatable').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Content("~/Person/Get")',
            "aoColumns": [
                            { "sName": "ItemID", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "visible": false },
                              { "sName": "CusID", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "visible": false },
                             { "sName": "Name" },
                            { "sName": "Description" },
                            { "sName": "Image", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false },
                            { "sName": "Price" }
            ]
        }).makeEditable(
        {
            'sAddURL': '@Url.Content("~/Person/Add")',
            'sDeleteURL': '@Url.Content("~/Person/Delete")',
            'sUpdateURL': '@Url.Content("~/Person/Update")',
            "aoColumns": [
                            { "sName": "ID", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "visible": false },
                              { "sName": "CusID", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "visible": false },
                             {
                                 indicator: 'Saving...',
                                 tooltip: 'Click to select customer',
                                 loadtext: 'loading...',
                                 type: 'select',
                                 onblur: 'submit',
                                 data: GetCustomers(),
                             },
                            { "sName": "Description" },
                            { "sName": "Image", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false },
                            { "sName": "Price" }
            ]

        });

    });
```

Comment: What code are you currently using to makes changes to the inline fields in the datatable ( without the popup )?

Comment: @gerdi - I just added code in my question

Comment: One more thing, popup works fine. I can add record successfully with this. But I need to upload image as well as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: ok .. You should edit the question to reflect that. This could just be a case of not adding an [enctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) to your form.

Comment: I didn't get you. I am looking for 'how to upload image using datatables in popup'

Comment: yeah , if you are posting images for a save your form needs to reflect that ,using enctype. You cannot post a image without `enctype="multipart/form-data"`